# In a group: how to filter the maximum of a column

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bigdata

[Imagen code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOCA6.png)

I have a base of movies, which I grouped by semester but I need to show only the highest grossing movie of that group. (max 'revenue')
Also I need to show it graphically, how can I do it?

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: @Vitalizzare I use this dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/akshaypawar7/millions-of-movies  
And group it by semester with the following: 

df_spark = spark.read.csv("..movies.csv", header=True)
df1 = df_spark.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='release_date', freq="2Q")])

however this will bring me the list of movies that are in a certain semester. I need to show only the one with the highest revenue for each group.

Comment: Have you tried `apply(...)` to filter data?